# Looking for a earth model that I can customize

Tags: xml, gis

I am looking for some kind of earth model that at run time can pick up some data from an xml file and display it on the earth based on lan or lon etc.Is there something like that ? Any OpenGL or flash where I don't have to do coding just feed the thing.Can someone shed some light on available ways to accomplish this.Something on the lines of [geocode earth](http://www.geocodearth.com/) or twitter earth but lan or lon mmm or what ever..

Comment: Not sure of your exact requirements, but if it's any help I use Google Earth for something similar. If you associate .kml files with Google Earth, then just opening them will fire up Google Earth and display the points (specified by latitude and longitude) on the Earth.

I have a Reporting Services report that spits out a KML file, so someone clicks on the report, it runs, fires up Google Earth, and displays the results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AThere is a FOSS lot of software /frameworks to deal with GIS and KML.

I would suggest importing your x,y in QGIS using the text delimiter plugin.

Then save the layer as KML and open it directly with Google Earth or even google maps

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific about how your xml data is defined. The most common standards are KML, GeoRSS, GML. These formats rely on lat,long so you should be good for that part.

If your XML does not conform to this then you will probably need to convert it first. But if you just want an app to pick it up then I would suggest that you ensure that it is properly formatted. This way most geo apps will be able to read it.